# Difficulty getting Login Approval from Facebook Review for headless application

Tags: facebook

I have a headless Facebook app that we've been running for 4 years. It is a bit unique in that, a) it has no user display b) it isn't available on the public internet it is hidden behind firewalls.

I use the standard Facebook Login Page during configuration of our app merely to get a permanent access token and authorize permissions. The only permissions I need are publish_actions, publish_pages and manage_pages.

I've tried to submit the approval form for this app to Facebook and get complete rejection because I haven't provided screen shots of what they see when they log into the app. I can't do that because as I said, it's headless and not available on the public internet. The response I get from the reviewers is completely canned with no thought on their part as to the restrictions of my app.

Does anyone know what I can do to get this app approved? As I mentioned, we've had this app on Facebook for 4 years prior to April 30, 2015. Is there someone I can talk to at Facebook? I've tried to explain the situation in the submission form, but obviously that didn't work.

Comment: Instead of screenshots, can you provide command-line examples showing what is happening? Or somehow explain when you publish something? Please note that pre-filling is not allowed; so if you are publishing without user interaction, you will not be approved. Can you show any UI that resolves in the published posts?

Comment: The path of least resistance is likely to create an authenticated web app, and in your submission details provide credentials so the reviewer can see a login page and authorize your app.